# Will this light loop increase a lights intensity?

Tags: electromagnetism, visible-light, fiber-optics

I know that professional labs can do interesting things with light loops and variations there of. My question is can an amateur like me increase the intensity of a weak light source by using a fiber optic loop. Here’s a pic of what I am thinking:[image]In the gap between the ball lenses I plan to pass a mirror on a rotating disk to reflect light out of the loop. Any chance this will work?If so, what would be a reasonable gain to expect in intensity?

Comment: Think you have to explain the reasoning behind your idea in detail and why you think that it will increase the intensity of a light source.

Comment: Okay. Here’s my reasoning. Light will enter the loop through the first ball lens and be focused. It will pass through the gap and enter ball lens number two and then into the fiber optic cable. It will travel through a length of cable say 10 meters. It will then enter the first ball lens again and repeat the process, but on each round trip it will be joined by ( added to) new light which is continually sending new light into the loop. The result should be an increase in the amount of light traversing the loop. Light will be lost, but will there be a net gain? That’s what I am not sure about.

Comment: Two problems. (1) The light will exit through the same portal. For example, if the portal is a 50:50 mirror, then 50% in, 50% out, no gain. (2) The losses are dramatic, because the light would circle the loop so many times that it won't last for a microsecond. However, you can do this with a non-linear amplifying element and two light sources. The light from one source would be absorbed and re-emitted amplifying the light from the other source, just like in a laser. See figure 3 here: https://www.rp-photonics.com/fiber_loop_mirrors.html

Comment: The rotating disk would only block the light when the mirror passes through the gap. It would be more like a fan blade configuration than a disk.

Comment: Does that change anything?

Comment: This is not possible; you could use it to build a perpetual motion machine. The light coming out of the end won't go back into the beginning the same way as the light from the light source - unless you put the end in front of the light source which blocks the light source. You might be able to get 2 loops.